# Is there a way to set up model associations when you generate a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to rails and wondering if there is a way to have all the associations you generate from a migration show up in that model. For example, working on a mock  AirBNB app. If i were to generate a migration like so (with these models already created)

```
rails g migration AddListingsToNeighborhood listing:belongs_to
```

When I run rake db:migrate, my models are still empty. Just wondering if there is a shortcut to have these associations fill the models.

Thank you!

Comment: Look for `references` in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not created the model (or can overwrite it), use

```
rails g model Neighborhood listing:references
```

If you have the model and just need to create the appropriate migration:

```
rails g migration AddListingsToNeighborhoods listing:references
```

The DB migration ***will not*** modify the model.

In these examples, `Neighborhood` gets the foreign key.

If you want `Listing` to have the foreign key (and have `belongs_to`), then you would need to reverse them:

```
rails g model Listing neighborhood:references

rails g migration AddNeighborhoodToListings neighborhood:references
```

FWIW, as you grow your apps, you will often be modifying existing models and adding relationships. This means manually adding `belongs_to` and running the migration.